# Intersection Of Two UIViewImages

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, intersection, closest-points

How can I determine if two uiviewimages intersect. I want to do an auto snap feature. When the small image intersects with the big image or close to it (Lets says the distance<=x), I want the small image automatically snap(connect) to the big image at the point where they intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous two posters have been on the right track with `CGRectIntersectsRect`.

```
BOOL isIntersecting = CGRectIntersectsRect(smallImage.frame, largeImage.frame);
if(isIntersecting){

    //Animate the Auto-Snap
    [UIView beginAnimation:@"animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    smallImage.frame = largeImage.frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Basically what this says that if the two images are intersecting, the small image frame snap to the larger image over 0.5 seconds.
You don't have to animate it though; you could just make it instantaneous by removing all code except for `smallImage.frame = largeImage.frame;`. However, I recommend the animation way.
Hope this helps.

-------EDIT--------

You could use the code:

```
 BOOL isIntersecting = CGRectIntersectsRect(smallImage.frame, largeImage.frame);
 if(isIntersecting){     
     //Animation
     [UIView beginAnimation:@"animation" context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

     smallImage.center = CGPointMake(largeImage.center.x, largeImage.center.y);

     //If you want to make it like a branch, you'll have to rotate the small image
     smallImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(30);
     //The 30 is the number of degrees to rotate. You can change that.

     [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Hope this fixed your problem. Remember to up vote and pick as the answer if this helped.

-------EDIT---------
One last thing. I said that the "30" in `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(30)` stood for 30 degrees, but that is incorrect. The CGAffineTransformMakeRotation function takes its parameter in radians, so if you wanted 30 degrees you could do this:

```
#define PI 3.14159265

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(PI/6);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.This works very well. Only problem is the small image goes inside the big image. I want something like this. Lets assume the small image is a branch of a tree. The big image is a big branch. When the small branch intersects with the big branch, the small branch's origin will connect to the surface of the big branch like in here http://postimage.org/image/u5790gt05/ . Should I use CGRectIntersection method?

Comment: The CGRectIntersect method returns `YES` if they intersect and `NO` if they don't. I'll add more in my above post...

Answer (score 2):

```
CGRect bigframe = CGRectInset(bigView.frame, -padding.x, -padding.y);

BOOL isIntersecting = CGRectIntersectsRect(smallView.frame, bigFrame);
```

Comment: what are padding.x and padding.y? Sorry I am a newbie :)

Comment: You only really need the second bit but you could inset by -padding to make a bigger rect for the smaller view to snap into the bigger one when it is not quite intersecting the view itself. You could use the same value for x and y if you want or declare a cgpoint

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CGRectIntersectsRect method to check for frames:

```
 if (CGRectIntersectsRect(myImageView1.frame, myImageView2.frame))
    {
        NSLog(@"intersected")
    }
```